# Method continues without waiting for task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

### Context

In the example below is a part of a ViewModel in an app (Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS and Windows Phone 8.1 RT). I have a property called `IsLoading` that indicates if something is loading. I then have something in my view bound to this property that shows a loading indicator. The method below is trigger by a command that is executed when the constructor of the ViewModel is called.

### Problem

The method continues without waiting for the inner task to complete. The loading indicator should be visible for at least 5 seconds, but the `IsLoading` property is set to false right after it was set to true.
This happens on all platforms.

### Example code (with MVVM Light)

```
public class ExampleViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get { return _isLoading; }
        set { Set(ref _isLoading, value); }
    }        

    private RelayCommand _loadCommand;

    public RelayCommand LoadCommand => _loadCommand ?? (_loadCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await LoadSomething()));

    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        LoadCommand.Execute(null);
    }

    private async Task LoadSomething()
        {
            if (IsLoading)
            {
                return;
            }
            IsLoading = true;
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
            }
            catch (SomeException exc)
            {
                // handle exceptions
            }
            finally
            {
                IsLoading = false;
            }
        }
}
```

The ViewModel itself is instantiated in the view on each platform (using IoC, Autofac).

Comment: 1) Are you invoking `PropertyChanged`? 2) How is `LoadSomething` called? 3) Please post a minimal but complete (reproducible) example.

Comment: @StephenCleary, I updated the sample to a complete ViewModel.

Comment: You are calling LoadCommand inside the constructor. At this point the ExampleViewModel class isn't initialized yet, much less bound to the View. Most likely, your command finishes before the framework had a chance to bind `IsLoading` to any controls

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You were correct. Moving the loading out of the constructor fixed the issue. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding what async await does. You are essentially running the threads asynchronously https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx. If you are in debug mode the thread will continue running which is why you are noticing that the thread is not waiting on the delay.

Comment: The thread keeps running, but why doesn't it wait for the delay before setting `IsLoading = false;`?

Comment: @SamuelDebruyn are you sure it doesn't wait? The way the code is written, `LoadSomething` may never run and the result would be the same. Moreover, you are calling the command from inside the constructor, before the viewmodel gets bound to any view